# Storm Fail Method Implementation

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am testing the storm(0.9.3) guaranteed message processing. In my topology I have one spout which reads message from Kafka and pass it on to a bolt which write it to a file and fails it.

Here is the code

**Kafka-spout**

```
import random
import storm
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('kafka_spout')
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR,filename='/tmp/kafka_spout.log',format="%(message)s",filemode='a')
import csv

class KafkaSpout(storm.Spout):
    def initialize(self, conf, context):
        self.consumer = KafkaConsumer("test",group_id="test_group",metadata_broker_list=["broker:9092"],auto_commit_enable=False,auto_offset_reset='largest')

        self.conf=conf
        self.context=context
        self.log_test="yes"


    def nextTuple(self):
        for message in self.consumer:
            tup_id=random.randrange(999999999)
            file_handle=open("/tmp/kafka_spout.csv","a")
            writer=csv.writer(file_handle,delimiter=",")
            writer.writerow([tup_id,message.offset,message.value,message.partition])
            file_handle.close()
            self.consumer.commit()
            self.consumer.task_done(message)
            storm.emit([tup_id,message.offset,message.value,message.partition],id=tup_id)

    def fail(self, id):
        f=open("/tmp/failed_tuples.txt","a")
        f.write(str(id)+"\n")
        f.close()

    def ack(self, id):
        f=open("/tmp/acked_tuples.txt","a")
        f.write(str(id)+"\n")
        f.close()


KafkaSpout().run()
```

**Test-Bolt**

```
import time
import storm
import csv
import random

class TestBolt(storm.BasicBolt):

    def initialize(self, conf, context):
        self.context=context
        self.conf=conf

    def process(self,tup):
        tup_id1,offset,message,message_partition=tup.values
        tup_id2=tup.id
        file_handle=open("/tmp/test_bolt.csv","a")
        writer=csv.writer(file_handle,delimiter=",")
        writer.writerow([tup_id1,offset,message,message_partition,tup_id2])
        file_handle.close()
        #time.sleep(random.randrange(29,38))     #test for replay on time out, but did not work.
        storm.fail(tup)

TestBolt().run()
```

**Topology Definition**

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("KafkaSpout", new KafkaSpout(), 1);
builder.setBolt("TestBolt", new TestBolt(), 4).shuffleGrouping("KafkaSpout");


Config conf = new Config();
conf.setNumWorkers(2);
conf.setMaxSpoutPending(1000);
StormSubmitter.submitTopologyWithProgressBar(args[0], conf, builder.createTopology())
```

As commented by Vor I editted my Spout and fail method worked. Here is the new spout definition

**New Kafka Spout**

```
    from kafka import KafkaConsumer
    import logging
    log = logging.getLogger('kafka_spout')
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR,filename='/tmp/kafka_spout.log',format="%(message)s",filemode='a')
    import csv

    class KafkaSpoutNew(storm.Spout):
        def initialize(self, conf, context):
            self.conf=conf
            self.context=context
            self.log_test="yes"


        def nextTuple(self):
            consumer=KafkaConsumer("test3",group_id="test_group",metadata_broker_list=["broker:9092"],auto_commit_enable=False, auto_commit_interval_ms=1 * 1000,auto_offset_reset='largest',consumer_timeout_ms=15000)

            try:
                message=consumer.next()
                tup_id=random.randrange(999999999)
                file_handle=open("/tmp/kafka_spout.csv","a")
                writer=csv.writer(file_handle,delimiter=",")
                writer.writerow([tup_id,message.offset,message.value,message.partition])
                file_handle.close()
                consumer.task_done(message)
                consumer.commit()
                storm.emit([tup_id,message.offset,message.value,message.partition],id=tup_id)

            except kafka.common.ConsumerTimeout:
                pass

        def fail(self, id):
            f=open("/tmp/failed_tuples.txt","a")
            f.write(str(id)+"\n")
            f.close()

        def ack(self, id):
            f=open("/tmp/acked_tuples.txt","a")
            f.write(str(id)+"\n")
            f.close()


    KafkaSpoutNew().run()
```

**Questions**

1. My fail or ack methods do not seem to be working as the files
      `/tmp/failed_tuples.txt` or `/tmp/failed_tuples.txt` are not
      created. Why?
2. Why the id provided in spout by `id=tup_id` is not same as the id
   noted in bolt by `tup.id` ? And which ID is used by storm for
   acking?
3. Also how could the replay logic be implemented in such case? (Need suggestions.)

Comment: Does this line `for message in self.consumer:` blocks for ever?

Comment: Yes. consumer is a generator.

Comment: Do you have `ackers` enabled? On the `java` side. In other words can you post your topology definition

Comment: @vor I have added the topology definition in question.

Comment: @Vor from you hint of continous blocking and checking the nextTuple on https://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc/backtype/storm/spout/ISpout.html , I edited my spout and made it non blocking and fail method worked.
But answer for 2 & 3 is needed.